# InternalFailureException while executing the gemlin query

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

we have recently updated the Neptune Engine to version 1.1.1 (R7). Along with that we updated the gremlin as well to version 3.5.3.  As per this official doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.1.1.0.html .

After this upgrade we are facing the below error message

```
2023-03-02T11:50:01.184Z    d44416f3-82d5-4030-88f6-383d33860d7f    INFO    ERROR ResponseError: Server error: {
    "detailedMessage": "Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=478e7350-3f1a-4ff3-8415-c996160d6c5f, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(), hasLabel(person), has(objId, ******@gmail.com), outE(employer), has(app, FP), order(), by(timestamp, null), as(e), inV(), as(v), select(v), by([[], [valueMap()]])]], aliases={g=g}}}].",
    "requestId": "478e7350-3f1a-4ff3-8415-c996160d6c5f",
    "code": "InternalFailureException"
} (500)
    at Connection._handleMessage (/var/task/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/connection.js:316:9)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/connection.js:131:43)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Receiver.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:413:14)
    at /var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:379:23
    at /var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/permessage-deflate.js:298:9 {
  statusCode: 500,
  statusMessage: `{"detailedMessage":"Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=478e7350-3f1a-4ff3-8415-c996160d6c5f, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(), hasLabel(person), has(objId, ******@gmail.com), outE(employer), has(app, FP), order(), by(timestamp, null), as(e), inV(), as(v), select(v), by([[], [valueMap()]])]], aliases={g=g}}}].","requestId":"478e7350-3f1a-4ff3-8415-c996160d6c5f","code":"InternalFailureException"}`,
  statusAttributes: Map(0) {}
}
```

Below is the query we are using  :

```java
query=g.V().hasLabel(type).range(startIndex,endIndex).valueMap();
```

After the Upgrade the query is not executing as expected . After the upgrade is something needs to be changed in the query as well ??

Comment: The query in your error output appears different than the query that you've noted above.  The query in the error output is effectively `g.V().hasLabel('person').has('objId', <email_address>).outE('employer').has('app','FP').order().by('timestamp').as('e').inV().as('v').select('v').by(valueMap())`  This is generating an InternalFailureException (IFE).  You'll likely want to open an AWS support case so that an engineer can look at your cluster and determine what is causing the IFE.

Comment: Hi @TaylorRiggan thanks for the suggestion we are able to figure out it was some config issue. Now the above query is working fine but struck with a new error.
 
Error: The child traversal of [[],[["addV","organization"],["property","objId","XXXXXXXXXXXXX"],["property","type","organization"],["property","link","employer"]]] was not spawned anonymously - use the __ class rather than a TraversalSource to construct the child traversal .

Comment: From the release notes we found that there are several breaking changes introduced in TinkerPop 3.5.0, 3.5.1, and 3.5.2 which may affect your Gremlin code. For example, using traversals spawned by a GraphTraversalSource as children like this will no longer work: g.V().union(identity(), g.V()). so ,we modified below query 
linkedVertexQuery = g .inject(1).coalesce(g.V().has('objId',links[i].objId),linkedVertexAddQuery )
in to this by replacing g with __ but still we could see same error 
linkedVertexQuery = g.inject(1).coalesce
(__. V().has('objId', links[i].objId),linkedVertexAddQuery)

Comment: linkedVertexAddQuery internally call this function . Is there something we are missing out that needs to be changed in below code as well ?
exports.createAddVertexQuery = (g, type, addObject) => {
 var query = g;
 if (type) {query = query.addV(type);} 
else {throw 'Vertex Type Not found in the request';}
 var nameFound = true;
 var objIdFound = false;
 var vertexKeys = Object.keys(addObject);
 for (var j = 0; j < vertexKeys.length; j++) {
  if (vertexKeys[j] === 'links') {continue;}
  if (vertexKeys[j] === 'linkAttributes') {continue;}

Comment: query = query.property(vertexKeys[j],addObject[vertexKeys[j]]);
  if (vertexKeys[j] === 'name') {nameFound = true;}
  if (vertexKeys[j] === 'objId') {objIdFound = true;}}
 if (nameFound == false || objIdFound == false) {throw 'vertex name or objId not found in request';}
 return query;
};

Comment: If you are using a version of Neptune that supports 3.5.2 (or later), then you'll need to change any "nested" queries to use the anonymous traversal versus using a nested graph traversal source object.  This relates to Neptune Engine version 1.1.1.0 or later (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.1.1.0.html).